# how to create Salutation fields in salesforce

Tags: custom-field, picklist

Salutation like contact name with prefixes Mr., Mr.s. I have googled but didn't get the solution.[image]

Comment: Why can't you create a formula field using the standard Salutation field and the contact name fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many fields on native objects which you want to create on custom object but Salesforce doesn't allow to do so. Like Salutation, Compound Address field etc.

So the best in this case you can do is create a custom picklist field to get value from user and then create a formula field to display the result on UI. Or if you really want this then you need to override the edit page and need to replace it with custom page.

Comment: 1.Salutation__c(Mr.,Mr.s)  
2. Name__c 
3. FormulaField__c   But i need Name__c will be like Mr.John .if i create a formula field the record will display all the fields                                                         Salutation = Mr.                                                                                                  Name(default field) = John                                                                                                  FormulaField = Mr.John .But i don't need that. need only the field Name = Mr.John dont want to display salutation and formula field.

Comment: @ArjunPrasad thats not possible as of now.